# Get error description with .htaccess/PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm running an apache server, and I want the custom PHP error page to display the error number and error description. So for example, I have in my .htaccess:
`ErrorDocument 404 /?e=404`
And in my error page:

```
<?php
$e = $_GET['e'];
if($e === 404){
?>
Error: <?=$e?>
<?php } ?>
```

So it will display:
`Error: 404`
But I want it to show the description too, such as
`Error: 404 Not Found`
without having to pull from a database etc. in PHP. So is it possible to pass a parameter or something with .htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no magic that can translate the error code in a description for you. That doesn't mean you can't just continue on the path you already took:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /?e=404&desc=Not%20Found
```

Now the errorcode is in `$_GET['e']` and the description is in `$_GET['desc']`.